# How can get my asp.NET correctly rendered on a iPhone UIWebView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ios, ios5, uiwebview

I'm developing a secure Web Browser application in iOS and I can show correctly any page, but the ones that has been developed internally with .NET (aspx, C#, Framework 2 & 4) does not appear correctly. It's like the pages has no styles neither javascript functionality.

I can see that the application gets correctly the .css and .js files from server, but the UIWebView does not apply these files.

I've tested solutions like "UIWebview and IPhone content does not postback (ASP.NET Browser Capability issues)" and other related to the *.browser files, but it's does not work for me.

Any other .net pages (from a Sharepoint) works perfectly on the UIWebView, but not our internally developed applications.

Any clue?
Thanks!